# Subscription & Billing for SaaS providers (node.js based solution)

Tags: node.js, paypal, payment, subscription, billing

we are developing a SaaS (node.js) and struggling how we could manage our subscriptions and billing. First idea was Stripe, but there are limitations like no PayPal Integration, not covering all tax rules in Europe etc.

Is there a solution in node so we could integrate it seamless in our product? something like:
- subscription management
- provides payment cia Stripe, PayPal, amazon Pay
- creates invoices
- compliant to european tax law (reverse charge etc)

Any idea? I asked google (and other engines;)), no result.. there are so many saas build up on node, can't imagine there's no solution

best
Felix

Comment: Braintree is paypal's competitor to stripe, so check that out.

I don't know any pre-built solution to your problem though.  If you find something, please mention!

Comment: Mollie Payments offers a similar service now, seems to be a very good alternative from europe